# マストドンのローカルタイムラインを取得する

Tags: python, python3

マストドンのローカルタイムラインを1000個取得しようとしているのですが、
2回目以降のmastodon.timelineの実行で
MastodonAPIError: ('Mastodon API returned error', 500, 'Internal Server Error', None)   
が発生します。これはどうやって修正すればよいでしょうか。

```
from mastodon import Mastodon

mastodon = Mastodon(
    client_id="app_key.txt",
    access_token="user_key.txt",
    api_base_url = "https://mstdn.jp")

def main():
    time_line_list = []
    next_id = None
    loop = True
    toot_count = 0

    while loop:
        # ローカルタイムラインの取得
        timeline = mastodon.timeline(
            timeline='local',
            since_id=None,
            limit=40,
            max_id=next_id
        )

        loop = True
        next_id = timeline[-1]['id']
        toot_count += 40
        if  toot_count > 1000:
            break

        for toot in timeline:
            time_line_list.append(toot)

    for toot in time_line_list:
        print(toot)
```

Comment: Internal Server Errorとのことで、サーバ側に問題がある可能性があります。どのインスタンスをご利用でしょうか？また、この断片的なコードだと情報として不十分（利用しているライブラリが不明など）ですので、コード全体を示していただけると助かります。（認証情報等は秘匿してください）

Comment: 今日はうまくいくみたいですね。昨日はサーバーの調子が悪かったのかもしれません。とりあえず様子を見ることにします。